# Mono Runtime error

Tags: asp.net, .net, mono, raspberry-pi, runtime-error

I'm having a heck of a time trying to get Mono to host ASPX files on my Raspberry pi 3.  I've followed the Mono installation instructions and seem to have made some headway as before Apache wouldn't even recognize the aspx file.  Now it does but it spits back a run time error.  I'm not doing anything fancy with the ASPX file, simply created a MonoDevelop project and then copied it into the /var/www directory.  Instead of getting the page to load I get the following when I try to go to http://localhost/default.aspx

```
System.Web.HttpException
The resource cannot be found.
```

Description:

```
HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Details: Requested URL: /default.aspx
```

Exception stack trace:

```
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.AssertVirtualPathExists (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.Type requiredBaseType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance (System.String virtualPath, System.String inputFile, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String requestType, System.String url, System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url, Boolean ignoreContextHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Version Information: 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-10); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

I followed the installation instructions on Mono's website exactly so there has got to be something I'm doing or not doing post installation that I've overlooked.  I've read about the chmd process to make sure there isn't a read issue on the aspx file but that didn't seem to be the problem.  Can't I just copy the files over to the www directoy and have it work like I did?  I've been google the heck out of this to try and come up with ideas and just am at a complete loss for ideas on what to try.

I appreciate any suggestions anyone might be willing to provide.

Comment: does "default.aspx" exist? or it has another name?

Comment: it definitely does exists, I copied it into the directory I mentioned.  Initially I thought perhaps it wasn't in the right one so I copied it to the html directory and to the any other directories listed in the Apache config file to no avail.  Again, must be something small I'm overlooking perhaps???

Comment: is the exact route /var/www/html/default.aspx? Beware with upper/lowercase, it's sensitive.

Comment: Gusman, thanks for the suggestion.  I checked the path and it is exactly as you described and the entire path is lower case.

Comment: Very strange... try this (to ensure Apache is serving correctly from that folder, it may be misconfigured), add a "test.html" to /var/www/html with just a barebone html page and try to access it through http://localhost/test.html. If the file is not found then the problem is on the Apache configuration, else it's on the mono configuration (I assume you added mod_mono.conf to your apache conf file, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally figured it out.  Even though all the documentation I've read seemed to indicate I could just drop the site into default directly I decided to try to set up another one and see if that was the issue which it apparently was.

This was the solution and then I just moved my site there:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/

```
Alias /test "/usr/share/doc/xsp/test"
Alias /personal "/home/user/mypages"
AddMonoApplications default "/test:/usr/share/doc/xsp/test,/personal:/home/user/mypages"
<Location /test>
  SetHandler mono
</Location>
<Location /personal>
  SetHandler mono
</Location>
```